# I need to implement music player using AV Player in SWIFT

Tags: swift, audio-streaming, avplayer

I need to implement streaming music player using AV Player in SWIFT

that music file Stored in server.Please help me to any one..How to implement this one

Comment: Is there something in particular you need help with?  You're not likely to find someone to write the whole thing for you.

Comment: I need just steps ..how to implement this ..am new in swift thats why

Answer (score 1):

According to this: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_8_Video_Playback_using_AVPlayer_and_AVPlayerViewController

You could add following code in your ViewController, like viewDidLoad method or viewWillAppear, depends on the view will show repeatedly or not. If Yes, add it in the viewWillAppear method.

```
let player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

playerController.player = player
self.addChildViewController(playerController)
self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame

player.play()
```