# I need to know how to get information about which player is currently streaming (player, spotify, napster...)

Tags: ios, swift, spotify, mpmusicplayercontroller

I can get information (artist, album, title) of the song that is currently playing with:

```
let t = MPMusicPlayerController().nowPlayingItem?.title
```

It works fine when the music is streaming from the iOS Music Player. However, when the streaming is from other source (Spotify, Napster, Youtube, Tuneinradio, etc.) I can not get information.  How can I get this information for any app?

Comment: try this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427763/i-need-to-implement-music-player-using-av-player-in-swift

Comment: sorry but I do not need to play nothing in my app. My app is running and other app (Player, Spotify, Napster, ...) is playing something. I want to know the title of the song which is playing  in those apps to show it in my app

Answer (score 0):

Use the `nowPlayingInfo` dictionary on `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter()`:

```
let t = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]
```

`MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` class reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/index.html).

Comment: Allways returns null value from newPlayingInfo

Comment: It seems this API is for setting the info not to getting, and that's the reason of gets nil.

Comment: Ye, so is there any API to get it ?