# Get current song playing in Spotify on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

Accessing the `MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()` (code below) works for getting track info for what's playing in the Apple Music app, but is there a way we can access information of the current song playing in the Spotify app?

This code posted in this answer [I need to know how to get information about which player is currently streaming (player, spotify, napster...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33163272/i-need-to-know-how-to-get-information-about-which-player-is-currently-streaming) uses `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` which is nil whether using Apple Music or Spotify etc.

```
  let player = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()

    @IBAction func getMusicButton(_ sender: UIButton) {




        if let mediaItem = player.nowPlayingItem {
            let title: String = mediaItem.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle) as! String
            let albumTitle: String = mediaItem.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle) as! String
            let artist: String = mediaItem.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtist) as! String

            print("\(title) on \(albumTitle) by \(artist)")
        }

    }
```

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33163272/i-need-to-know-how-to-get-information-about-which-player-is-currently-streaming

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need to know how to get information about which player is currently streaming (player, spotify, napster...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33163272/i-need-to-know-how-to-get-information-about-which-player-is-currently-streaming)

Comment: No this code doesn't return info for Apple Music or for Spotify, please see my edits above

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I didn't @KyleGoslan my understanding is that it's a sandboxing issue whereas we can't detect what Spotify (a 3rd party app) is playing only with Apple Music is playing.

Comment: @GarySabo, it's odd, I'm not convinced that's the case. Spotify must be broadcasting the info to enable it to play/display info on the iOS media player, so it's odd that we can't then read that info. It appears that that's exactly what 'MPNowPlayingInfoCenter' is supposed to be used for, but returns nil: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpnowplayinginfocenter

Comment: @KyleGoslan that was my experience as well, and so I abandoned my project for now, if you do figure out a solution please repost here 

Comment: @GarySabo Will do. Frustrating! So easy to do if it's the music app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Apple Documentation states there are two types of music player:

> - An *application music player* plays music locally within your app. It is not aware of the Music app’s now-playing item, nor does it
>     affect the Music app’s state. There are two application music players:
>     `applicationMusicPlayer` and `applicationQueuePlayer`. The application
>     queue player provides greater control over the contents of the queue
>     and is the preferred player.
> - The *system music player* employs the built-in Music app on your behalf. On instantiation, it takes on the current Music app state,
>     such as the identification of the now-playing item. If a user switches
>     away from your app while music is playing, that music continues to
>     play. The Music app then has your music player’s most recently-set
>     repeat mode, shuffle mode, playback state, and now-playing item.

The first is only within your app and the second is the Apple Music app, since you can't reach out of your app's sandbox in a normal app this is not possible in App Store apps.

If however you still want to create your idea you can develop this on a jailbroken device. [This github project](https://github.com/gilshahar7/NotifyMusic/blob/master/Tweak.xm) has an easy example of how to get the current playing song in a jailbreak tweak. If you want to try it, [this](http://www.brandontreb.com/beginning-jailbroken-ios-development-your-first-tweak) is an excellent, be it a bit old, still accurate tutorial on how to get started developing tweaks.

---

**Update**

I just ran into [this Spotify SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/) that will let users login and play the users Spotify music. This way the music stream will be inside your app and you have access to all info in the applicationMusicPlayer. The downside is that this will be a lot more work to set up than just getting the information about Spotify's playing track and the user will have to play his music from your app instead of the Spotify app.

Comment: I think the sdk is build for something else. As per their description- "This framework contains functionality necessary to stream audio content from Spotify."

Comment: @Rishabh streaming spotify audio content means that the music information will be in your apps applicationMusicPlayer does it not?

Comment: Oh, I see. Thats probably correct. But i see an open feature request for this same thing at git: https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/issues/418

Comment: I think this answer is incorrect. The `Bose Connect` iOS app successfully does this. It can get currently playing media details and playback controls for `Audible` and `Spotify`. `Bose Connect` does require that the other apps be alreadyplaying for you to control playback and get media details. I am looking at replicating Bose Connect's playback feature. Though I wonder if the bluetooth audio device they connect to, QC35, is receiving the data and sharing it with the app, not systemMusicPlayer.

Comment: @Ryderpro I assume they do it through the bluetooth but it is possible that the api changed. This answer is a year old, if you find anything don't hesitate to update it!

Comment: @CasperZandbergen Your answer is accurate. API unchanged from what I'm finding. `Bose Connect` app gets current song playing from bluetooth headset via A2DP or another bluetooth profile.